# How do I display a timeline with amCharts for WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, amcharts

I'm trying do display a time line in wp7 using [amCharts quickCharts](http://wpf.amcharts.com/quick/general).

```
        <amq:SerialChart DataSource="{Binding MyData}" 
                         CategoryValueMemberPath="Date"
                         AxisForeground="White"
                         PlotAreaBackground="Black"
                         GridStroke="Gray"
                         Margin="1"
                         >
            <amq:SerialChart.Graphs>
                <amq:LineGraph ValueMemberPath="Score" 
                               Title="Scores" 
                               Brush="Blue"/>
            </amq:SerialChart.Graphs>
        </amq:SerialChart>
```

`MyData` is an `ObservableCollection<ScoreDate>` where `ScoreDate` is defined as

```
public class ScoreDate
{
   public int Score{get;set;}
   public DateTime Date{get;set;}
}
```

Problem is, that the X-Axis is just plotted as individual values, skipping periods without data, and not as events on a distributed timeline as I need it to be.

Any way to make amCharts do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is no easy feat as the amcharts for wp7 is too simple and apparently abandoned.

What I ended up doing was just creating my own graph with a PolyLine on a Canvas, databound to a PointCollection.

Got the graph right pretty fast.